# How to compare two arrays in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have two arrays.

```
let runArray = ['Welcome', 'Hello']

let data = [{
  Node:'Good',
  Session:'2',
  Run:'Welcome',
  Run_Group:'Display',
  Elapsed_Ms: '1000'
}]
```

I have like 2600 objects in `data` array and like 50 of them in `runArray`. And the number of elements could be more.

The point is to compare every index in `runArray` with `data[index].Run` propery so I can calculate the average of `Elapsed_Ms` property (from data).

Is there any options?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: I noticed, that you are new member at StackOverflow! Welcome aboard. Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking, and try to search for a solution before posting a question. You might also take a look at [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#difference) and it's `Array.difference` methods.

Comment: No, I tried to apply that logic but that did not work because it is a guarantee that all the elements in runArray are in data array. But they are repeated more than once. That's why I just want to calculate the average of Elapsed_Ms

Comment: What logic have you tried? I don't see any example of your (even not working) code. I also told you, that you could you `lodash` and compare array with your array of object value, and also StackOverflow has also a lot of such question, you don't need to duplicate them, just try to search.

Comment: And yes, I looked at loadash and it's Array.difference method. But I cannot use it because I know that all the elements that are in runArray will be in Run property of data.

Comment: 2600 items, you would want to use reduce for that, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141530/calculate-average-of-array-of-objects-per-key-value-using-reduce

Comment: Why do you need to "compare two arrays" to compute the average for a "Run"?

Comment: Because I want to calculate the average of each run @Jake Holzinger

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ciao, here a working example:

```js
let runArray = ['Welcome', 'Hello']; 
    let data = [{Node:'Good', Session:'2', Run:'Welcome', Run_Group:'Display', Elapsed_Ms: '1000'},
    {Node:'Good', Session:'2', Run:'Welcome', Run_Group:'Display', Elapsed_Ms: '500'},
    {Node:'Good', Session:'2', Run:'Hello', Run_Group:'Display', Elapsed_Ms: '1000'}];

    let averages = [];
    runArray.map(el => {
       let filteredArray = data.filter(dat => dat.Run === el);
       let avg = filteredArray.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b.Elapsed_Ms), 0)/filteredArray.length;
       let appo_obj = {index : el, average: avg};
       averages.push(appo_obj);
    })
    
    console.log(averages)
```

**Edit**: as @MattJHoughton suggested, a for loop is better for performance.

```js
let runArray = ['Welcome', 'Hello']; 
        let data = [{Node:'Good', Session:'2', Run:'Welcome', Run_Group:'Display', Elapsed_Ms: '1000'},
        {Node:'Good', Session:'2', Run:'Welcome', Run_Group:'Display', Elapsed_Ms: '500'},
        {Node:'Good', Session:'2', Run:'Hello', Run_Group:'Display', Elapsed_Ms: '1000'}];

        let averages = [];
        for(let i=0; i<runArray.length;i++) {
           let filteredArray = data.filter(dat => dat.Run === runArray[i]);
           let avg = filteredArray.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b.Elapsed_Ms), 0)/filteredArray.length;
           let appo_obj = {index : runArray[i], average: avg};
           averages.push(appo_obj);
        }
        
        console.log(averages)
```

Comment: Wrapping all this in a map function seems like it would be a bad idea for performance, as you're not intending to compute a new array from runArray, and you are building up the averages array inside the function. So you are not using the array created by map. Why not use a for loop?

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on your existing code, we need to loop on the values of your `runArray` finding any matching items in your `data` array, keeping a running sum of total elapsed time, and the data item count.

```js
let runArray = ['Welcome', 'Hello'];

let data = [{
  Node:'Good',
  Session:'2',
  Run:'Welcome',
  Run_Group:'Display',
  Elapsed_Ms: '1000'
}];

let sumElapsedMs = 0;
let numberOfItems = 0;

// loop over runArray
runArray.forEach((value) => {

  // find the first matching entry in data array
  const matchedDataItem = data.find((dataItem) => {
    return dataItem.Run === value;
  });
  
  // sum total elapsed & number of data entries
  if (matchedDataItem) {
    numberOfItems++;
    sumElapsedMs += matchedDataItem.Elapsed_Ms;
  }
});

// calculate average (else default: undefined)
const averageElapsedMs = numberOfItems ? sumElapsedMs/numberOfItems : undefined;

console.log('Average Elapsed (mS)', averageElapsedMs);
```